# How to prevent ArgumentError (A copy of PaymentFailed has been removed from the > module tree but is still active!) with StripeEvents / Webhooks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using the [StripeEvent gem](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) to handle web hooks coming from Stripe.

In my Rails initializer I've got this:

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|

  events.subscribe 'invoice.payment_succeeded', PaymentSucceeded.new
  events.subscribe 'invoice.payment_failed', PaymentFailed.new

end
```

I've also got a folder `app/stripe_events` where I keep classes like these:

```
class PaymentFailed

  def call(event)
    StripeMailer.admin_payment_failed(event.data.object).deliver_now
  end

end
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error every now and then:

> ArgumentError (A copy of PaymentFailed has been removed from the
>   module tree but is still active!)

I guess that's because everything inside `app` is constantly being reloaded by Rails while the `StripeEvent.configure` bits in the initializer are not?

How can this be prevented?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those running into this issue, the second argument to `events.subscribe` can be a lambda which clears this up:

```
StripeEvent.configure do |config|
  config.subscribe 'customer.subscription.created', ->(event) { 
    RecordStripeSubscription.new.call event 
  }
end
```

See https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event/issues/108.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only get this error when I make a change to the event handler or config files. Restarting the server always fixes it.